# Problem with Codewars Kata - Largest difference in increasing array

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to solve this Kata on Codewars: https://www.codewars.com/kata/largest-difference-in-increasing-indexes/train/javascript

> Consider all of the pairs of numbers in the array where the first one
>   is less than or equal to the second one.
>
> From these, find a pair where their positions in the array are
>   farthest apart.
>
> Return the difference between the indexes of the two array elements in
>   this pair.

This is what I have and can't figure out why it is not correct.

```js
var largestDifference = function(data) {
    arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) {
        for (var j = data.length-1; j>i;  j--) {
            if (data[i] <= data[j]) {
                arr.push(i)
            }
        }
    }
    ans = Math.max(...arr)- Math.min(...arr);
    return ans 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there; you need to push the difference between the indexes which is **`j - i`**, and then take the `Max()` of all those differences. Or if there are none, then return 0.

```js
var largestDifference = function(data) {
  arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = data.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
      if (data[i] <= data[j]) {
        arr.push(j - i)
      }
    }
  }
  return arr.length > 0 ? Math.max(...arr) : 0;
};

console.log(largestDifference([9, 4, 1, 10, 3, 4, 0, -1, -2]));
// 4 because data[1] <= data[5], so 5 - 1 = 4

console.log(largestDifference([3, 2, 1]));
// 0 because not found

console.log(largestDifference([1, 2, 3]));
// 2, because here j = 2 and i = 0 and 2 - 0 = 2
```

It can also be done a bit simpler (and more efficient) without helper array or `Max()`:

```js
var largestDifference = function(data) {
  let result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = data.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
      if (data[i] <= data[j] && result < j - i) {
        result = j - i;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(largestDifference([9, 4, 1, 10, 3, 4, 0, -1, -2]));
console.log(largestDifference([3, 2, 1]));
console.log(largestDifference([1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to push `i` to `ans` array. You need to push the difference of `j` and `i` i.e `j - i`

```js
var largestDifference = function(data) {
  let res = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    for(let j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++){
      if(data[i] <= data[j]){
        res.push(j - i);
      }
    }
  }
  return res.length ? Math.max(...res) : 0
};
console.log(largestDifference([9,4,1,10,3,4,0,-1,-2])) // 4
console.log(largestDifference([3, 2, 1])) // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to collect the deltas.

> Instead, you could take the max value direcly if found and use this value for preventing to loop over items who can not give a greater maximum.
>
> ```
>         |               |
> indices | 0   1   2   3 | 4   5   6   7   8
>         |     *         |     *              result
> values  | 9   4   1  10 | 3   4   0  -1  -2  max
>         | *           + | -   -   -   -   -   3
>         |     *         |     +   -   -   -   4
>         |         *     |             -   -
>         |             * |                 -
> ---------------------------------------------------- never visited
>         |               | *   +   -   -   -
>         |               |     *   -   -   -
>         |               |         *   -   -          * data[i]
>         |               |             *   -          - data[j]
>         | indices for i |                            + data[j] match
> ```

```js
var largestDifference = function (data) {
        var i, j, l = data.length - 1, max = 0;
        for (i = 0; i + max < l; i++) {
            for (j = l; i + max < j; j--) {
                if (data[i] <= data[j] && max < j - i) {
                    max = j - i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return max;
    };

console.log(largestDifference([9, 4, 1, 10, 3, 4, 0, -1, -2]));
console.log(largestDifference([3, 2, 1]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```